# Unable to pass custom express-validator check

Tags: javascript, node.js, express-validator

The purpose of the following code is to check whether an email already exists in MongoDB, using express-validator:

```js
    app.post('/registerPage',[check('email').custom((email) => {
    // connect to database
    let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    let url = 'mongodb://localhost';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
        if (err) throw err;
        let db = client.db('Mydatabase');
        // search database
        return db.collection('users').findOne({
            email: email
        }).then(user => {
                if (user) {
                   console.log(user); // here console shows correct record in database
                   return Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');
                }
                // otherwise, it returns null
        });
    })
}).withMessage('Error Message Example')], (req, res) => {
    // Handle the request
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
       return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }
  });
```

When email already exists, console shows `Promise.reject('E-mail already in use');`.

The problem is when email does not exist, although it doesn't show `Promise.reject`, the code cannot process any further, `validationResult(req)` is not empty, so it still prints out the error message '*Error Message Example*'. But there isn't any problem with non-custom validators which can successfully pass the checks.

I tried to add an `else` statement where `!user`, it doesn't work.

The question is how to pass the custom validation check, or why the array `validationResult(req)` is not empty even it should be? How do I make sure `validationResult` is empty after all checks were passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are returning the promise in the callback of `MongoClient.connect` and not the validator function. Try using Promise wrapper like:

```
app.post('/registerPage',[check('email').custom((email) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // connect to database
        let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
        let url = 'mongodb://localhost';
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
            if (err) throw err;
            let db = client.db('Mydatabase');
            // search database
            return db.collection('users').findOne({
                email: email
            }).then(user => {
                if (user) {
                console.log(user); // here console shows correct record in database
                return reject('E-mail already in use');
                }
                return resolve();
            });
        })

    });
}).withMessage('Error Message Example')], (req, res) => {
    // Handle the request
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() })
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!